# Generating an array for random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, random

Ok so I am creating an app that allows you to set a timer to a certain length of time and set a number of beeps. when you hit start the timer will play and however many beeps you selected will play at random times. In the code I have an array that I am trying to fill with numbers between 0 and the timer length:

```
for (int i=0; i< arraysize; i++){
    Random random = new Random();
    beepArray[i] = random.nextInt((0 - count)+ 1);
}
```

The program can run but it doesnt seem to fill the array with random numbers and so the timer stops and no beeps are played. Have I done something wrong here?

Thanks in adavance
Mark

Comment: What is the `(0 - count) + 1` supposed to do? What value do you have for `count`? What do you see when you run this in your debugger? How are you determining that it isn't putting random values in the array?

Answer (score 1):

Move the `Random random = new Random();` **out** of the loop:

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i=0; i< arraysize; i++){
    beepArray[i] = random.nextInt((0 - count)+ 1);
}
```

By default, [`Random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random--) seeds itself, and may end up using the same seed if you call it very quickly in succession. Pseudo-random number generators are deterministic and give the same sequence of "random" values starting from a given seed, so you want to seed it *once* and then let it run.